# Pages: How do I change the column size in the footer?

Tags: pages

In my Pages document, the footer has 3 columns. All three have the same width. Now I want to add text in each footer column but for that I have to change the width of the columns. How do I adjust the width of the columns in the footer?

Answer (score 3):

@Matthieu Riegler is correct.

The portion will automatically resize to fit.  Simply type in or paste your text.  See screenshot below:

[image: Footer expansion]

As noted in the comments, this only works when there is no content in the other columns. not quite what the OP had in mind.

Comment: But only if there's nothing else in the other columns right? Is there still no way to have different width columns if there's content in each column?

Comment: These will by dynamic but only to a point.  There is only so much space across the page. There appears to be no way to manually adjust that.  This could be a good subject for feedback to Apple.

Comment: I don't think it's to do with space. If there's text in each column, then each column is no longer dynamic and is in fact restricted to its default third. I finally found a workaround: only use the first column. As described in Option 3 here:  https://discussions.apple.com/message/32150197#message32150197

Comment: hmmm. good point. Sad to have to resort to a hacky workaround.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember well, the column extends itself if the text is longer than the cell.